# Not able to connect to docker containers using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, docker, lxc

I am new to Docker, I built the container from a Dockerfile, and I can see the container creating and running, but I am not able to connect to that container using ssh.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 & openssh-server

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 22

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Then I ran this cmd:

```
docker build -t="apache2" .
$ docker run -d apache2
```

When I do `docker ps`, I can see the port is assigned, but I am not able to connect to that container using ssh.

$ docker ps

```
ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS              PORTS
5765535796f8        apache2:latest      /usr/sbin/apache2 -D   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   49154->80,49155->22
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there's a typo in your docker file.  Line:

`RUN apt-get install -y apache2 & openssh-server`

should be

`RUN apt-get install -y apache2 openssh-server`

If you change this as well as add the steps to setting the root password as shown in the "running an ssh service guide" are you able to ssh into your running container?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply johncosta,I need some clarification can't we connect to the container when we run this command "docker run -d apache2".

Comment: You need to start the openssh-server parallel to the apache2 process. Docker has no init/supervisor and ONLY starts the process you specify.

Answer (score 3):

in addition to installing ssh, you need to run the sshd service (you are only running apache)

This can be accomplished by using something like `supervisord` or targeting a `startup.sh` script instead of `apache` in the `ENTRYPOINT`

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 openssh-server

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 22
ADD ./startup.sh /opt/startup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sshd

apache2 -D FOREGROUND
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution allowed my to start the sshd daemon using the following command (embedded in a bash script executed in the docker file) - /usr/sbin/sshd -D &

Answer (score 2):

IMHO your looking for

`docker attach 5765535796f8`

[Docker Commands](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/command/attach/)

edit:

`docker attach 57` should work as well.

edit2:

When creating your container make sure to name it, restart, set environment variables and path to persistent data, expose the ports needed:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name=<my_container> -e TZ=<timezone> -e TERM=xterm -p <some_unused_port>:22 -v -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /path/to/persistent/data:/data maintainer/image_name
```

afterwards you can access the container like this:

```
docker exec -it <my_container> /bin/bash
```

re: running ssh in a container

Security wise that is not such a good idea.

Also letsencrypt is very handy - port 443 ;)

Comment: There are reasons to ssh into a docker container rather than attach to it.  Of course you would normally attach when possible, but if you're troubleshooting ssh-specific stuff such as ssh agent forwarding...