# git ssh can't access to gitlab in a docker container

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, docker

I installed gitlab in a container with docker, which already `EXPOSE 22`. When I `ssh -vv git@host.com` I can't access with ssh publickey, only password method works.

How can I get ssh access to an docker container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem.

`sudo docker run -p 2222:22 -d something`, this will redirect port `22` of the Container to `2222` of the HOST, then I can login to the Container with `ssh host.com -p 2222`.

Comment: Nice redirection. +1. My answer was more in the installation side.

Comment: How about if you want to be able to push to `git@server` without using `:2222` ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on:

- how you installed that openssh service within your docker container (see "[Not able to connect to docker containers using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18565903/6309)")
  See that [more recent example](http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/development/2014/01/docker-containers-nuxeo-part-1/) (January 2014)

  ```
  # Install apache and ssh server
  RUN sudo apt-get install -y openssh-server apache2 postgresql-9.3
  RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
  ```
- if you do have a `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file with the right public key in it.